# Weird equation - why is that possible?

Tags: calculus, summation

I have found the following equality:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{n+1} = 1$$

Why is that possible? I mean the left side is bigger than 1 for any $n>0$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No, the left hand side sums $n+1$ terms, each with the value $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: AHH - I kinda handled that n like a k - oh god thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ is a constant, not depending upon $k$. The sum is over $k$. So, you are summing $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ $(n+1)$ times.